# Fetch rows from one table with reference to a row with list of data from another table using single query

Tags: mysql

I have a table *tblA* having feilds *a1*, *a2* with following data

```
a1        a2

1       1,2,3

2       4,5

3       6,7,8,9
```

Another table *tblB* having fields *b1*, *b2* with following data

```
b1          b2

1         b2a

2         b2b

3         b2c

4         b2d

5         b2e

6         b2f

7         b2g

8         b2h

9         b2i
```

Now, with reference to *a2* field from *tblA* and *b1* field from *tblB*, we have to fetch the data of *b2* field from *tblB*

I have used the following query

```
SELECT b2 FROM tblB WHERE b1 IN (SELECT a2 FROM tblA WHERE a1 = 1)
```

This fetched just one row of 1,i.e. the data is b2a

But I need the list of data like

b2a

b2b

b2c

Please help me out with the proper solution. One thing to be careful that I need a single query to fetch the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `FIND_IN_SET`. *[DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)*

```
SELECT b2 FROM tblB WHERE FIND_IN_SET(b1, (SELECT a2 FROM tblA WHERE a1 = 1)) != 0
```